# Query to Filter Date fields in MongoDB collection in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, date

Version for MongoDBDriver (2.15.0)

```
using MongoDB.Driver;

public async Task<List<Employee>> GetBirthAnniversary()
{
    var today = DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime(); // Ensure consistent comparison in UTC

    var filter = Builders<Employee>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Employee>.Filter.Eq("IsDeleted", false),
        Builders<Employee>.Filter.Eq("EmployeeStatus", "Active"),
        Builders<Employee>.Filter.Exists("BirthDate"),
        Builders<Employee>.Filter.Where(employee =>
            employee.BirthDate != null &&
            employee.BirthDate.Value.Month == today.Month &&
            employee.BirthDate.Value.Day == today.Day
        ));

    return await _context.DefaultEmployee.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
}
```

Another attempt:

```
public async Task<List<Employee>> GetBirthAnniversary1()
{
    var today = DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime(); // Ensure consistent comparison in UTC

    var filter = Builders<Employee>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Employee>.Filter.Eq("IsDeleted", false),
        Builders<Employee>.Filter.Eq("EmployeeStatus", "Active"),
        Builders<Employee>.Filter.Exists("BirthDate"),
        Builders<Employee>.Filter.Where(employee =>
            employee.BirthDate != null &&
            Builders<Employee>.Filter.Regex("BirthDate", new BsonRegularExpression($"^{today.Month:D2}-{today.Day:D2}"))
        ));

    return await _context.DefaultEmployee.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
}
```

I have a 'BirthDate' field in MongoDB, that is a Date time field, I store UTC date time field. The logic I want is to get the dates, matching the Day and the Month only, do not consider the Year.
Now, this logic not working properly. I am getting error like: {document}{BirthDate}.Date is not supported." How do I modify the query, retrieve the records based on the filter.

```
// Employee.cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace MyProject.EmployeeMicroservice.Data.Model
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Employee
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public long EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public long? CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public long? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public string TenantCode { get; set; }
        //[BsonIgnore]
        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfJoining { get; set; }
        public long? Reportingto { get; set; }
        public long? Office { get; set; }
        public long? Department { get; set; }
        public long? Designation { get; set; }
        public long? Grade { get; set; }
        public long? Team { get; set; }
        public long? EmployeeGroup { get; set; }
        public long? EmployeeType { get; set; }
        public long? ContractAgency { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnore]
        public string EmployeeSchemaId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeStatus { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ProbationStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ProbationEndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ContractStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ContractEndDate { get; set; }

        //[BsonIgnore]
        public Int64? CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string OffboardingType { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SettlementDate { get; set; } = default!;
        public string SettlementStatus { get; set; } = default!;
        public DateTime? LastWorkingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string UAN { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeTag { get; set; }
        public bool IsMandatoryFieldsFilled { get; set; } = default!;
        public List<long> ReporteesIds { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This implementation is working fine.

```
//NotificationService.cs

        /// <summary>
        ///  Sending birthday notification to Employee
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task SendDOBNotification()
        {
            //Filter out the employee records that do have a BirthDate value set
            List<Employee> lstEmployeeDOB = await GetEmployeeDOB();

            //send notification On the day of birthday of employee
            await DOBNotification(lstEmployeeDOB);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Sending notification alert One day before the Birthday of employees to Hr 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task SendDOBAlertNotification()
        {
            //Filter out the employee records that do have a BirthDate value set
            List<Employee> lstEmployeeDOB = await GetEmployeeDOB();

            //send notification on One day before the Birthday of employees
            await DOBAlertNotification(lstEmployeeDOB);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  This method retrieves employee list to track the date of birth 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeeDOB()
        {
            List<Employee> lstEmployeeDOB = new List<Employee>();
            Employee objEmployeeDOB;
            var employeeAllList = await _employeeRepository.GetEmployees();

            foreach (var objEmp in employeeAllList)
            {
                objEmployeeDOB = new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeCode = objEmp.EmployeeCode,
                    FirstName = objEmp.FirstName,
                    LastName = objEmp.LastName,
                    EmailId = objEmp.EmailId,
                    HrManagerId = objEmp.HrManagerId,
                    TenantCode = objEmp.TenantCode,
                    EmployeeID = objEmp.EmployeeID
                };

                if (objEmp.BirthDate.HasValue)
                {
                    objEmployeeDOB.BirthDate = objEmp.BirthDate;
                    lstEmployeeDOB.Add(objEmployeeDOB);
                }
            }
            return lstEmployeeDOB;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// send notification On the day of birthday of employee
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lstEmployeeDOB"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task<List<Employee>> DOBNotification(List<Employee> lstEmployeeDOB)
        {
            lstEmployeeDOB = lstEmployeeDOB.Where(dob => dob.BirthDate.HasValue && dob.BirthDate.Value.Day == DateTime.Today.Day && dob.BirthDate.Value.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && dob.BirthDate.Value.Year != DateTime.Today.Year).ToList();
            foreach (var objDOB in lstEmployeeDOB)
            {
                await SendDOBNotificationToEmployee(objDOB);
            }
            return lstEmployeeDOB;
        }

// EmployeeRepository.cs


        public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees()
        {
            return await _context.DefaultEmployee
                    .Find(c => !c.IsDeleted && c.EmployeeStatus.ToLower() == "active").ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: A DataTime is stored as UTC and  is then converted to TimeZone when converting to a string so no need to use ToUniverslaTime.   Not sure why you are using BirthDate.Value.  Value is not needed is BirthDate is a DateTime.  So I think BirthDate is a string an not a DateTime.  So try DateTime.Parse(employee.BirthDate.Value).Month

Comment: Which version of the driver do you use? What is the exact error that you are receiving? Can you also add the part of the `Employee` class that contains the `BirthDate` property? I've done a short test and it worked without any problem.